# sql select statement select sum where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temp tables (below), the first marks one of five conditions. The second pulls from that table and does a sum and a count based on the condition. How could I get the second table to work with this, or a similar format?

```
select ID
     ,sum_value    
     ,condition_field
     ,'condition_1' = case when condition_type in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end
     ,'condition_2' = case when condition_type in (3,4) then 1 else 0 end
     --etc...
into #temp    
from my_table

select ID
     ,sum_value
     ,'1_amt' = SUM(sum_value) from #temp where condition_1 = 1
     ,'1_cnt' = COUNT(ID) from #temp where condition_1 = 1
     ,'2_amt' = SUM(sum_value) from #temp where condition_2 = 1
     ,'2_cnt' = COUNT(ID) form #temp where condition_2 = 2
from #temp
```

Comment: Is this even working?

Comment: What is it, MySQL or SQL Server? You can't use the same code in both.

Comment: The first query is, however the second is not, I get a syntax error after the '1_amt' sub query

Comment: @waterguard what error? And what database *are* you targetting?

Comment: fixed I got lazy used the first tags I saw. I'm using MSSQL

Comment: incorrect syntax near , (referring to the next line down) if I remove the extra lines, only focus on '1_amt', I get incorrect syntax near from

Comment: 1_amt is it a variable, should it  not be alias to subquery in select.

Comment: Well, the second SELECT isn't valid SQL for any product. You can't mix FROM etc right in the SELECT clause. Check how to create subqueries

Comment: So a nested select statement doesn't work in the select clause? Only the from clause?

Comment: Why didn't you use CASE in the second query like you did in the first?

Comment: You have a select from from from... What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Thanks tab, when the two minutes have passed, Ill mark that as the answer.

Comment: Why don't you use a stored procedure to solve this?
`select ID, sum_value, sp1(ID,sum_value), sp2(...)`

Comment: I've been taught to avoid them like the plague, It leaves junk around on the servers and It is something that can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something more like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN condition_1=1 THEN sum_value ELSE 0 END) AS 1_amt
```